# Which is the best way to convey "You're lucky that you're not here" in Russian?

Tags: словоупотребление

The translators all give different meanings but which is the most appropriate way to say it? 
Твоё счастье, что ты не здесь ( счастье’s main meaning is happiness)
Тебе повезло, что тебя здесь нет (повезло = what a score) 
вам повезло, что вы не здесь
What are the difference between these and whats the usage difference between повезло и счастье?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Твоё счастье, что...** and **тебе повезло, что...** are both **You were lucky enough** not to (have been here, go there, have such an angry teacher).

There's no real difference between them.

Comment: Although there's no difference in meaning, I think 'Твоё счастье' is a little bit outdated. Not all, but most natives today would usually say 'Тебе повезло' or 'Тебе везёт'.

Comment: @Arthur Kazykhanov, I would say, it depends...

Answer (score 1):

I'd say a more probable option would be "**Радуйся, что ты не здесь**".

It's quite common to hear constructs like that starting from "радуйся, ...". The meaning literally is "you should feel joy because...", essentially exactly what you are asking "you are lucky, that ...".

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать несколько разных переводов, которые по смыслу ничем не отличаются.

1) Тебе повезло, что тебя здесь нет.
2) Твоё счастье, что ты не тут.
3) Везёт же тебе, что ты сейчас не здесь.

И многие другие варианты. Русский язык гораздо многограннее, чем английский.

Comment: должно быть именно поэтому ваш комментарий на русском